# Stop an Android app with UiAutomator/UiDevice

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

My app is bound to the service of another app (I don't have the source code of this one). I want to test the case when the binding with the service is broken. For this, I have a manual test where I run the adb command `adb shell am force-stop com.package.to.stop`.

What I would want is to send this particular ADB command in my tests that use UiAutomator.
I have something like...

```
uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
uiDevice.executeShellCommand("am force-stop com.package.to.stop")
```

...but this doesn't do anything. I was thinking about permissions related to this particular command, but I'm not able to find something on this topic. Of course, if I change this command to another one (such as `pm list packages`), this is working like a charm.

Any help/comment appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

`android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES` is a privileged permission only granted to system apps.

Privileged apps should have also to be *allowlisted* in `privapp-permissions.xml`.
More details can be found at https://source.android.com/docs/core/permissions/perms-allowlist.

Comment: This is not answer to the quastion.